# The same imported report does not get the parameter value

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am importing the same report 3 times. For each iteration, I am passing a different value, but the problem is that only the first imported report gets the value, the other two are blank. Here is my code:

```
foreach (var current in reportParameterList)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(current.SubreportName))
    {
        document.SetParameterValue(current.Name, current.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        document.SetParameterValue(current.Name, current.Value, current.SubreportName);
    }
}
```

So, for the where is subreport name blank, that is for the main report, the else case is for my subreports. So, the same report, imported 3 times doesn't show the value on the second and third.

**UPDATE:**

The method for filling values for subreports:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _reportLayoutConfiguration.ReportLayout.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (_reportLayoutConfiguration.ReportLayout[i].SubreportName == "SectionReportTest1.rpt")
                    {
                        SetSectionOneReportParameters(reportParameterList);
                    }
                    if (_reportLayoutConfiguration.ReportLayout[i].SubreportName == "SectionReportTest2.rpt")
                    {
                        SetSectionTwoReportParameters(reportParameterList);
                    }
                    if (_reportLayoutConfiguration.ReportLayout[i].SubreportName == "SectionReportTest3.rpt")
                    {
                        SetSectionThreeReportParameters(reportParameterList);
                    }
                }

private void SetSectionOneReportParameters(List<ReportParameter> reportParameterList)
        {
            reportParameterList.Add(new ReportParameter() { Name = "SectionParameterID", Value = "ParameterOne_" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "", SubreportName = "SectionReportTest1.rpt" });
        }

        private void SetSectionTwoReportParameters(List<ReportParameter> reportParameterList)
        {
            reportParameterList.Add(new ReportParameter() { Name = "SectionParameterID", Value = "ParameterTwo_" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "", SubreportName = "SectionReportTest2.rpt" });
        }

        private void SetSectionThreeReportParameters(List<ReportParameter> reportParameterList)
        {
            reportParameterList.Add(new ReportParameter() { Name = "SectionParameterID", Value = "ParameterThree_" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "", SubreportName = "SectionReportTest3.rpt" });
        }
```

Of course, this is for testing only.

Comment: Could you paste some more code? Not only setting the parameters but also the main loop where you import the report?

Comment: I am not sure what should I pass, because I have 3 parameters in the reportParameterList... Name, Value and SubreportName. If the name is the same, my error occurs. @owczarek

Comment: The name of the parameter? So you are three times setting the value to the same parameter. Check the collection `reportParameterList` if the values are correct.

Comment: The name of the parameter is the same, the value of it is different. I can not have different name of the parameter if the reports are the same. @owczarek

Comment: When do you import the report? Inside this `foreach` loop you pasted (but you removed the line) or outside? If outside, so the value is overwritten two times.

Comment: OK, you got the update. @owczarek

Comment: Check if this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037550/how-to-send-parameters-to-subreport-in-crystal-reports There is the difference in setting the subreport name parameter